# Missing function in ViewPager from Android compatibility library

Tags: android, compatibility, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm trying to use the function `setOffscreenPageLimit()` in ViewPager, but Eclipse says *The function `setOffscreenPageLimit()` is undefined for the type ViewPager*

However, I see it in the docs and in many examples.  [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29)

Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyView {
    private final ViewPager viewPager; 

    MyView (ViewPager viewPager) {
       this.viewPager = viewPager;
       viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); //<-- can't find it
    }
}
```

I think it must be some strange problems with the library.  My minSdk is 7 and target is 13.  I've pressed "check for updates" many times and even tried manually re-importing the compatibility library but this function still doesn't show up.  Any ideas?  I really need this function!

Comment: just to confirm - you're using it on an instantiated ViewPager object and not statically, correct? Maybe post your code...? I'm using the compat library and it works fine. How large is the compat lib you're using? Mine's 243KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that .setOffscreenPageLimit() was a recent addition to the android support library. You should update your support library to the newest (currently v9) using Android SDK Manager. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and the solution was to add the jar file to the libs directory AND add it to the build path in the projects properties. Do not add the file as an external jar, click "add jar".

Hope this helps.